# how to list all pull request with name , ID , Date created and count of files

Tags: github

I am looking for an option in github to get all pull requests with ID, Name, Date and count of files committed.

I tried to use the export option and used the below command but couldn't get full data.

git ls-remote orgin'pull/*/head' and from this i can get the list of files committed, but couldn't get name and date. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance